# Excel Chart Several Y values against one X Value

Tags: excel, charts

I have a multiple columns representing Y values each against a specific x value. I am doing a scatter plot. When plotting each series, I can easily select the y values as they are present in columns but the x value is constant for each column and I cant seem to figure out how to repeat a constant x value against several y column values.
Does someone know how to provide a single repeatable value in the text box "X-Values"?

Answer (score 5):

Arrange your data like this, then select the range of cells containing ALL the Y-values, and from the ribbon, do Insert Chart | Scatterplot.

Is this what you expect?  Each *Series* in this chart represents one *Column* of data.  The X-Values are not repeated, nor do they need to be repeated.

[image]

You may need to slightly adjust the range for the values, you can do this by "grabbing" the blue/purple outline of the range, and resizing it , like:

[image]

If you don't like the default/numeric X-axis labels, then create the chart as a Line chart, initially, and then format the series so that there is "No Line", the result should look like a scatterplot, except it will use the Category Labels:

[image]

Comment: Completeness - the best reason to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you probably should reshape your data to a single series, so that you have 2 columns and many rows.  Column A keeps x values, column B the corresponding y values.

So, from this:

```
   A  B  C  D ...
1  10 13 16 17
2  11 14    18
3  12
```

to this:

```
   A  B  C  D ...
1  xa 10
2  xa 11
3  xa 12
4  xb 13
5  xb 14
6  xc 16
7  xd 17
8  xd 18
```

Comment: Even with this, lets says i have one x value and 100 y values corresponding to it. I have to click that x value 100 times while selecting corresponding x's for each of the y. something like ={A1,A1,A1.....100 times}

Comment: Just select both columns of data and click the chart icon and select scatterplot.... or am I mistunderstanding what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea if you still need to find out how to do this, but I had the same problem and the 1st answer here inspired me to try something... and it worked. Basically you just repeat the x value n times for the corresponding y values in a separate column. Say your x values are 2.5, 5, 7.5, and 10, and your y values are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 (2 y's for each x), in column A you would put 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, and in column B you would put 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have data like this:

```
   A  B ...
1  3  2
2     5
3     7
```

You could create a named formula in Formulas -> Name Manager (lets call it `ConstA1`)

```
=Sheet1!$A$1*ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3)/ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3)
```

and reference it in the 'Series X values' field for the series on a scatter plot

```
=Book1!ConstA1
```

while plotting `=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3` on Y axis.
Also consider using Data Tables. 
Inspiration: [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/673749-create-one-dimensional-array-single-cell-repeating-cells-value-n-times.html)